# Plotly graph does not show when jupyter notebook is converted to slides

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, reveal.js, nbconvert

I have a jupyter notebook with interractive plotly plots.  I am converting that notebook into slides using `nbconvert`.  When I do so the plotly plots do not show up in the slides.  I get the following tornado warnings as well

```
$ jupyter nbconvert presentation.ipynb --to slides --post serve
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook presentation.ipynb to slides
[NbConvertApp] Writing 818538 bytes to presentation.slides.html
[NbConvertApp] Redirecting reveal.js requests to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.1.0
Serving your slides at http://127.0.0.1:8000/presentation.slides.html
Use Control-C to stop this server
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 1.53ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.96ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /plotly.js (127.0.0.1) 0.84ms
```

To add insult to injury this worked yesterday and I don't think I changed anything substantial.  I tried rebooting my browser and my machine and neither helped.

Comment: Did you find out how to get it working? I have the same for saving to markdown.

Comment: No, I never got this to work.

Answer (score 12):

1) Check the JS console for errors and the Jupyter log if you are serving the slides via Jupyter. When you browse the slides.html, you may be getting
404 GET /files/mydir/plotly.js

put the plotly.js file in the directory where the slides.html is located (download e.g. https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js and rename to plotly.js)

2) make sure you are specifying a Layout height and width in your Jupyter notebook e.g.

```
trace_data = [trace1]
layout = Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=720,
    height=480,
    margin=Margin(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ),
    bargroupgap=0.3
)
fig = Figure(data=trace_data, layout=layout)
```

Re-run your charts, check they appear properly in the notebook, save the notebook, re-run nbconvert.

You do not need to customize the custom.css and make a myreveal.tpl Reveal template and specify it on the nbconvert command line, but you can do so if you wish to customize your slides.

Answer (score 3):

Following the code found here : https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/format/slides/github/tarokiritani/testjupyter/blob/master/test%20plotly.ipynb#/

I have found adding `plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)` into the same cell as the `plotly.offline.(i)plot` function works

Answer (score 1):

You must have a plotly.js file in your directory where you are performing nbconvert.  For some reason, "to html" will embed the plotly javascript into the HTML file, but "to slides" searches for a plotly.js file in the directory.

That said, you will have to template reveal.js to change dimensions of the slides depending on the size of your plot charts.  That, or customize the dimension of the plotly graphs.  If the slide are too big (or the other way around), the graphs will collapse into one line in the slides.